# Quite a lot -vs- a lot ( what is bigger?)

Tags: quantifiers

I've seen other answers, but they don't give enough information. There is a question in a book, to compare the amount of cookies on different plates. In my opinion, quite a lot is bigger, but I can't find any information to prove or disprove it.

[image]

Comment: If you've got quite a bit of something, or quite a lot of something, you have a fairly large amount of it. “A lot” suggests a larger amount than “quite a lot”.

Comment: Lexico's [**quite**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/quite) meaning **1** is "completely" but in this context, meaning **2** "to an extent" is more apt, so "a lot" is more than "quite a lot", and I support the view of @user070221 especially as the phrase choice is not just "a lot" but "a lot/lots" and "lots" means "very many".

Comment: @user070221 That's opposite of my understanding. "Quite a lot" sounds like more than "a lot." In general, "quite" (in this sense) serves to amplify a companion adjective, such that e.g. "this brick is quite heavy" is synonymous with "... **very** heavy."

Comment: I don't think that 'quite a lot' is necessarily more than, or less than, 'a lot'.

Comment: Well, of course, neither "a lot" nor "quite a lot" are precisely quantities, so in that sense, "quite a lot" isn't necessarily less than "a lot".  That said, in British English, "quite a lot" connotes a smaller quantity than "a lot".  For example, if someone asks me "Were there a lot of people there?", and I say "Quite a lot", that's a more equivocal answer than "Yes".

Comment: ***quite*** is an ***intensifier*** (like ***right, very, extremely***), so all things being equal, ***quite a lot*** implies "more" than plain ***lots, a lot***.

Comment: ...but note that ***quite*** has a range of usages, from *She's quite pretty* (*somewhat* pretty, but nothing remarkable) to *It's quite dead* (*completely* dead, with no hope of being revived).

Answer (score 1):

[Oxford](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/quite) defines 'quite' to express 'to the utmost or most absolute extent' in its first definition.
[MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/quite-a-lot-a-bit-a-few) defines 'quite alot' as 'a large number or amount', so the expression would mean 'the largest amount'.

The reality is it's an informal method of expressing a larger amount. And normally found only in conversational speech.

Comment: This brings to mind a scenario in which someone was asked if they experienced more then one headache a month and the response was "way, way more". Pointless elevation of an uncounted amount.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer.  I'm not sure whether it's true of AmE (since AmE and BrE often use the word "quite" differently: in BrE, "it was quite good" means "it was fairly good", "it was good to a certain extent", and "it was quite full" means "it was fairly full, but not completely").  In BrE if we say "quite a lot" it means a fair number, but by no means the largest amount.

Comment: @rjpond - I was going to say the exact same thing.  "Quite" in the UK is frequently used to mean a moderate amount, certainly not the highest amount. It's also used to avoid saying something negative out of politeness.  For example "The meal was quite good" - which basically means it was shit.  Americans don't seem to use it in this sense, so it's something to be aware of. Perhaps down to the British habit of understatement or not saying what we actually mean.

Comment: From a British perspective A=some greedy b*st*rd ate all the biscuits, B=this is all you are allowed, but you better leave one for me! C=quite a lot (a moderate amount), and D=a lot, and you should only have one or two, and politely refuse another, or we will talk about you when you leave. Culture and etiquette can be such a funny thing!  I'm not the downvoter BTW. Was that really necessary??  Upvoted +1

Comment: Based on the original question, this is the correct answer.  The dictionary definition says *quite* is the **utmost**, meaning *quite a lot* > *a lot*.  However, Billy's and rj's observations also apply to AmE.  In my experience the use of *quite* is entirely contextual and can be used to express a greater, lesser, or equal amount of emphasis on the noun's characteristics.  For example, *That was quite a snowstorm*, can be understood based on the characteristics of the snowstorm.